# REST - Getting specific property of resources in collection only

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

I'm developing the search functionality of my REST API and currently URI's structured  as:

```
api/items?type=egg,potato
```

Let's say each item resource has 4 properties:

Id, Name, Type, Rating

What would be the most restful way to design my URI and return a subset of properties of each resource, e.g. **only** names of these resources?

--

The reason I ask this is I often want a less heavy duty result-set. For instance, I may build an AJAX search with dynamically populated names as dropdowns - but I do not want extra bloat coming back with each request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST isn't really a set of rock-solid standards, but there are some nice practices.

In this particular case I would recommend using the query parameter of an existing resource field as you are now, to select items which have the `type` value of `egg` or `potato`. But to select only a subset, you can introduce a `field` query parameter. So you can call your API like `api/items?type=egg&fields=name`, to get only the `name` field of all the resources with the `egg` type.

P.S
This is not my invention, I already seen this in other API's, somewhere called `select`. As far as I know, Facebook has this feature in its API's.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good way to do it. I'm wondering - would it ever make sense not to include the ID? (i.e. should I always force it as a field?)

Comment: I guess that really depends on your use case and the meaning of the ID. If the client is expected to reference that resource again soon, I would include the ID always. If not, than you don't need to.